# Unable to view text files on putty using the less command

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, text, less

After invoking the less command in putty,it keeps on returning that the text file is a directory without showing the text in the directory.

Actual command: less file_name

ls -l gives -rw-r--r-- l

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the filename you are passing to `less` really is the name of a directory not a text file. If you are sure that is not the case then please [edit] your question with more details (such as the actual command you used, and the output of `ls -l` on the file in question)

Comment: Actual command used: less file_name, output of ls -l: -rw -r--r-- l